# How to display text in 2 lines in a ui:button on a Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css

I have a Lightning Component with a ui:button and I need to display the text in 2 lines
My custom style is :

`.THIS .button { 
 width: 150px; 
 color: #00396B;

 border: 2px solid #005FB2;

   }`

My ui:button look like this:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
      <ui:button label="Residential Landlord"                     
                 class="button"
                 press="{!c.openResidentialform}" />
      </div>
```

Thanks,
Sylvie

Comment: <ui:button label="Residential Landlord"    try Residential \n Landlord or Residential <br/> Landlord

Comment: None of these work, sorry. \n is displayed in the button and when I add  <br/> I have an error message "The value of attribute "label" associated with an element type "ui:button" must not contain the '<' character."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the following changes :-

**Component**

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
   <button class="slds-button customButton" onclick="{!c.openResidentialform}"> 
       Residential Landlord 
   </button>
</div>
```

**Style**

```
.THIS .customButton { 
   width: 150px; 
   color: #00396B;
   border: 2px solid #005FB2;
   padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Button]

**Or**

you may include `<br/>` tag like this without any changes to your CSS

```
<button class="slds-button customButton" onclick="{!c.openResidentialform}"> 
    Residential <br/> Landlord 
</button>
```

ui:button creates a span (inside the button tag), so it's better to use just `<button>` tags (Every other functionality does work with this method ).

PS: *It's better to avoid using standard element names as custom class names (here, in this case, usage of "button" as a class name), as it will avoid confusion and make easy while debugging design issues in the future.*

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. I use the 2nd solution but have to set the height otherwise the button with one word are smaller.